# MonoTouch Bluetooth/Arduino example

Tags: xamarin.ios

Has anyone used bluetooth communications from an iOS device to an Arduino?

The documentation for the MonoTouch 5.0 release mentions a new Bluetooth interface, but I can't find a single piece of documentation in the API docs.

"Bluetooth
Using the MonoTouch Bluetooth APIs you can easily access and communicate with external Bluetooth hardware devices and accessories."

Comment: Android has good support for Arduino. You can connect directly by wire.

Answer (score 2):

Look in MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.

That said, iOS only has support for Bluetooth LE (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0 and Smart Bluetooth), not the regular Bluetooth, which is only available under a special partner program with Apple.